# Parser from XML to Excel files

Tags: xml, excel, xml-parsing

I look a parser that will export XML file data to EXCEL files.
Preferably in C++ or Python.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Parsers parse. They don't export. It's a 2-step exercise. Using Python:

Step 1: Parse your XML data into a tree, using xml.etree.cElementTree.

Step 2: Map your tree contents into Excel's (sheet, row, column) structure using xlwt.

Answer (score 0):

There's Eric Gazoni's openpyxl
More details available from his [blog](http://ericgazoni.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/openpyxl-python-xlsx/). and the code repository is on [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/)

Or there's a lilinks to xlrd, xlwt and xlutils at http://www.python-excel.org/

Or look at [pyExelerator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyexcelerator/)

Comment: pyExcelerator is abandonware.

Comment: @John - I'll have to direct everyone to xlrd and xlwt instead then :)